# Is mirroring Stripe (Subscriptions, Invoices, Coupons...) in your own local database efficient?

Tags: php, paypal, wordpress, stripe-payments

Is mirroring Stripe with your own local database is a good thing?

Mirroring using both API calls (create a new plan, coupon, subscription, etc.) and webhooks (new invoice or charge generated, payment failed.) so you can store all data (literally have similar tables with columns matching the stripe objects) locally and work with it faster.

If not, what data do you save locally and what do you request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, saving the same data in two different places is not a good idea. By avoiding data duplication, you save a lot of time and prevent possible issues like data being out of sync.

That being said,

1. You do not control data saved on Stripe's side. If it disappears for any reason, you are in trouble. Even though such an event is highly unlikely, I would recommend to store locally the most critical information.

In my apps I typically store Stripe's customer ID and which plan a user is subscribed to. Obviously, I also have all plans in my code since they determine what a user can do within an app.

2. You may want to store some data locally for performance reasons, but a call to your own database is not necessarily faster than an API call. More importantly, even if there is a difference of a few hundred milliseconds, users will not notice it. And most users access such data (list of their invoices, etc.) very infrequently.

Comment: Let's say you use plans/subscriptions with Stripe. Your client subscribes so you stored locally his stripe customer id, the plan id, the subscription id and some data such as period_start/period_end and the likes.

But what about having the monthly/recurring invoices and charges done by stripe? Would you wait for the user to visit your page to have the API called and have them showed? Same for regular charges.

Comment: Of course. Most users check their payments, etc. very rarely. There is no problem if they have to wait extra 0.5 seconds for this data to be displayed. Stripe API, in my experience, is fast.

Comment: So If I need to check if a customer has an active subscription I can call stripe API, which will always return the truth , instead of storing subscription data on my local DB.
Also , in this case I may not need web hooks  making everything simpler

Answer (score 1):

The strategy you're describing is exactly the one I am using.

Basically, using Stripe is a bidirectional thing: sometimes you initiate the request (when creating a new customer for example), sometimes they do (when canceling a subscription because a credit card is failing for example).
In the first case I save the Stripe response (which is a JSON) in my database. In the second case, I save the Stripe webhook (which is a JSON too) in my database too.

In order not to choose which customer or subscription fields to save in DB, I save the whole JSON in PostgreSQL using a `JSONB` field. There is almost no performance overhead, and it is very simple to query the data.

Doing this you have the best of both worlds:

- Speed (since you are reading local data instead of remote data)
- Ease of development (you don't have to think to much about which Stripe data you are going to save)
- You're safe in case of disaster on the Stripe side
- You data is always up to date

I actually even wrote an article about that, in case it helps:
https://juliensalinas.com/en/storing-stripe-payment-data-database/

Comment: Julien, @JulienSalinas which webhooks do you have Stripe send? Do you send every subscription related webhook (about 15) and every customer related webhook (about 13)? Also, when you say you save the JSON, do you have a table with 1 customer record field that has subscription_json and customer_jason, and then do you overwrite the existing subscription_json or customer_json with the new data or do you update individual elements of it?

Answer (score 0):

Like Andrei said, it is nice to not have to worry about data duplication issues. Their API is plenty fast for most use cases, but if you need to make it faster, you can create temporary caches using redis or memcached. This is especially important if Stripe's API has any unexpected downtime.

Most SaaS companies like Stripe recommend backing up your data as an extra precaution. So if some of your Stripe data is accidentally deleted, or a Salesforce contact is changed, etc... then you can always recover it from a backup. This also covers you in the very unlikely event that Stripe's data is compromised.

Seems unlikely but you never know if you don't control it yourself. Capital One was hacked last year and I would've never thought it would happen.